# Having Trouble calling a class at different times

Tags: java, processing

First off apologies for not being able to word my question accurately!

The problem I face is I have an array list with 4 classes that do the exact same thing , only that they need to be called at different times (when the first one's coordinate exceeds a certain value) but Im having trouble getting it done , and Cant find it online (probably because I cant word my questions accurately :/) anyway I will post my code below and if anyone could shed some light I would be extremely grateful!

**What im making is a a tunnel effect by connecting the center of the screen with each corner with lines, and now im attempting to simulate moving by starting lines coming from the middle of the screen towards the edge (starting with bottom portion) **

```
    speedLines sline1, sline2, sline3, sline4;

// holds speedLines classes
ArrayList<speedLines> gameObject;

void setup() {
  background(0);
  size(750, 750);
  smooth();

  gameObject = new ArrayList<speedLines>();

  sline1 = new speedLines(height/2);
  sline2 = new speedLines(height/8);
  sline3 = new speedLines(height/4);
  sline4 = new speedLines((height/2)*3);

  gameObject.add(sline1);
  gameObject.add(sline2);
  gameObject.add(sline3);
  gameObject.add(sline4);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for(int i=0; i< gameObject.size(); i++){

    // go through the different classes
    // 2 added so far
    gameObject.get(i).display();

  }
  Guidelines();
}
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
int line=0;
int linewidth=0;




void Guidelines() {
  stroke(255);
  //MAIN GUIDE
  line(0, 0, width/2, height/2);//top left guide
  line(width, 0, width/2, height/2);//top right guide
  line(0, height, width/2, height/2);//bottom left guide
  line(width, height, width/2, height/2);//bottom right guide
  //SUB GUIDE
  stroke(60, 60, 60);
  line(width/3, height, width/2, height/2);//sub guide left
  line((width/3)*2, height, width/2, height/2);//sub guide right
}
class speedLines {
  //Global variables
  int Y;

  speedLines(int y) {
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(60, 60, 60);
    line((width/2)-linewidth, (height/2)+line, (width/2)+linewidth, (height/2)+line);
    line++;
    linewidth++;
    if ((height/2)+line >= height)
    {
      line=0;
      linewidth=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try to narrow this down to a smaller example sketch. I'd also try to clean up your code a bit: is there a reason you have sketch-level `sline` variables when you put them in the `ArrayList` anyway?

That being said, I'll try to help. You're passing a parameter into the `speedLines` class (which should really be called `SpeedLine` since classes should start with an upper-case letter and each instance only represents one line) constructor, but you're never using that parameter. Try to get it working with just one instance, like this:

```
Line myLine;

void setup() {
  size(100, 500);
  myLine = new Line(height/2);
}

void draw() {
  background(200);
  myLine.move();
  myLine.render();
}

class Line {
  float lineY;

  public Line(float lineY) {
    this.lineY = lineY;
  }

  public void move() {
    lineY++;
    if (lineY > height) {
      lineY = 0;
    }
  }

  public void render() {
    line(0, lineY, width, lineY);
  }
}
```

Notice how I'm actually using the `lineY` variable that I'm passing into my `Line` constructor. Try to get something like this working in your code. Then it'll be easier to use an `ArrayList` to draw multiple lines:

```
ArrayList<Line> myLines = new ArrayList<Line>();

void setup() {
  size(100, 500);
  for (float lineY = 0; lineY < height; lineY += 100) {
    myLines.add(new Line(lineY));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(200);

  for (Line myLine : myLines) {
    myLine.move();
    myLine.render();
  }
}

class Line {
  float lineY;

  public Line(float lineY) {
    this.lineY = lineY;
  }

  public void move() {
    lineY++;
    if (lineY > height) {
      lineY = 0;
    }
  }

  public void render() {
    line(0, lineY, width, lineY);
  }
}
```

Also note that you're only ever really using a single value in your class (in my example, the `lineY` variable). So you probably don't really need a class to do this. You could probably do this with just an array of `float` values that hold the `lineY` values instead:

```
float[] lineY = new float[10];

void setup() {
  size(100, 500);
  for (int i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++) {
    lineY[i] = i * 10;
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(200);

  for (int i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++) {
    lineY[i]++;
    if (lineY[i] > height) {
      lineY[i] = 0;
    }
    line(0, lineY[i], width, lineY[i]);
  }
}
```

Please note that all of these are just examples, and you'll have to take these examples and understand what they're doing, then do similar things in your code. Good luck.